# Bug? Convert-to-comment on answer with negative displayed vote count causes loss of rep

Tags: support

This answer of mine was converted to a comment (we can argue about whether that was appropriate but I'll let that go):

[Does C++ already have some kind of reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312493/does-c-already-have-some-kind-of-reflection/6312516#6312516)

The answer had -1 total votes; presumably that had previous impact of -10 on my rep.  I'd expect that converting an answer to a comment would remove the reputation that went with the answer.

Yet my rep dropped by 6 points; I'd expect it to go up by 10.  (I'd place a picture of my rep change here, if Vista would let me take a screen snapshot. Sigh). 
Here's a copy of my rep display via cut-and-paste.

```
14  today
+10     10 hours ago    upvote  Static code parser for Java source code to extract methods / comments
+10     11 hours ago    upvote  Good PHP Metric tools
-6  25 mins ago     removed     Does C++ already have some kind of reflection?
```

Answer (score 10):

The vote split was actually +1 / -2 which translates to +10 -4 = +6 reputation. Up-votes are worth +10, while down-votes are worth -2.

So when the post was removed you lost 6 reputation points - all perfectly legal and by design.

Comment: OK, I understand this answer.  What's confusing is the shown value on the answer is "-1".

Comment: @IraBaxter -1 is the net score. If you click on the number it splits into separate values for up and down votes (it's a privilege you get at 1,000 reputation)

Comment: yes, I know that :-{  must just be too early in the morning to do arithmetic, and convert-to-comment doesn't happen very often.

Answer (score 2):

The -1 score can be explained by 1 upvote and two downvotes, which would have given you (10-2*2) = 6 reputation, that looks correct to me.

Upvotes on answers give -10 reputation, downvotes give -2 reputation. A single downvote will never result in a -10 reputation penalty as you write in your question.